# How to add more than one piece of data to an array follow the .each method

Tags: ruby, arrays, iterator, each

I have the following method:

```
def speciate 
  chem_formula.each { |chemical|
    @chem_species = chemical.scan(/[A-Z][^A-Z]*/)
    puts @chem_species
  }
end
```

that produces:

```
H2
S
O4

@chem_species = ["S", "O4"]
```

from: `@chem_formula = ["H2" "SO4"]`

**How do you set the array to include all iterations?** That is how do you output `["H2", "S", "O4"]` rather than `["S", "O4"]` Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant as you're building an array then flattening but this works:

```
@chem_formula.map{|chem| chem.scan(/[A-Z][^A-Z]*/) }.flatten
```

Comment: I have to disagree, this *is* elegant :)

Comment: i say not so elegant as there are multiple array iterations going on here under the hood.  While yes, it's one line and *looks* very pretty and elegant, I think too many Ruby developers forgot that these Ruby array functions .each, .map etc... all iterate over arrays, making them comparatively slow to a custom built algorithm. ie. this could certainly be achieved with a few lines of code and a SINGLE iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
def speciate
  @chem_species = []
  chem_formula.each { |chemical|
    @chem_species.concat(chemical.scan(/[A-Z][^A-Z]*/))
    puts @chem_species
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way is:

```
@chem_formula.flat_map{|chem| chem.scan(/[A-Z][^A-Z]*/) }
```

*Note*: `flat_map` is Ruby 1.9.2+. You can `require 'backports/1.9.2/enumerable/flat_map'` if using an older Ruby, or else use `map{}.flatten(1)`.